# An open in Banach space if connected if and only if is path-connected $C^{\infty}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, homotopy-theory, curves

To prove the that An open in Banach space if connected if and only if is path-connected $C^{\infty}$ I'd like to prove the following :

> $\textbf{Lemma :}$ Let $U$ be open in a Banach space and $D \subset U$ be dense. If $x,y \in U$ are connected through an arch $\gamma \subset U$ it exists a polygonal $\delta \subset U$ which connects $x,y$ whose junction points are in $D$.

I think I was able to find a relatively simple costruction of $\delta$, the problem is that in the junction points the function could be not $C^{2}$.

(The real task was to prove that, given an homotopy $C^{0}$ between two curves $\gamma_{1},\gamma_{2} : [a,b] \longmapsto (X,d)$ without loss of generality I can take a $C^{2}$ homotopy using the Lemma above since, $C^{2}$ function are dense in $C^{0}$)

I think this can be done using the function $e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$ because it has all null derivatives in $0$, but I don't know how since this argument is new to me.

Any help, hint, reference or other method to the real purpose will be appreciated.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about TVSs. To me it seems that your problem is an easy consequence of the local convexity of Banach spaces, and introducing the lemma isn't necessary. (It also leads to an easy solution of the lemma).

Comment: @Tyrone I'm sorry what's TVSs ? I was trying to find a solution for the homotopy question, and this seemed a way which could have brought some new knowledge to me. If you could reply with a complete answer to the Lemma/Problem I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: TVS = topological vector space. The point is that each point of a curve has a open neighbourhood which is a convex ball. Thus you proceed exactly as you would in finite dimensional space.